# delete object as attribute from function

Tags: python-3.x, class

I want to delete an object using a function.

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

foo = Test(5)

def delete(obj):
    del obj

delete(foo)
print(foo)
```

In this code here, I am expecting it to give me an error on the last print statement, but it is printing my object, which I don't want. I want it to be deleted.
How would I go about doing so?

Answer (score 0):

I will bite.

`del obj` deletes the locally-available reference to `obj` inside `delete`.

You will see it if you add any reference to `obj` inside `delete`:

```
def delete(obj):
    del obj
    obj
```

This causes the expected `UnboundLocalError` when calling `delete`.

Instead of `del obj` you can delete `obj` from the global namespace but you will have to use the name of the reference:

```
def delete(obj_name):
    del globals()[obj_name]
```

then

```
class Test():
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.x = x

foo = Test(5)

def delete(obj_name):
    del globals()[obj_name]

delete('foo')
print(foo)
NameError: name 'foo' is not defined
```

**BUT** Is there another goal you didn't explain? This on itself is a bit of a weird problem to be wanting to solve (ie XY problem). Why not let Python's GC handle the deletion of objects?

Comment: As you already mentioned, you really shouldn't do this. But if OP insists on it, you can get  the object name from within the function with the `inspect` module. `global_dict = inspect.currentframe().f_back.f_locals.items()` to get the `globals()` dict. and then `obj_name = [name for name, value in global_dict if value is obj][0]` to get the variable name to `del`. Assuming the local variable in the functions name is `obj`.

Comment: If this seems like an x and y problem, I'll tell you what I'm using this for. I'm making a game and it is going to load enemies on to a map (the map is a list of lists) . Each enemy is an object, when the player defeats the enemy (when the enemy health, an attribute, is 0 or smaller). I want to delete the object so then it won't be displayed on the map. So I have a function called battle, where the enemy and player battles, and when the enemy's health reaches 0 or smaller, I want to delete it.

Comment: @aaa In this case it will be a lot easier to simply leave the `player.health` on `0`, then when drawing the map only draw those with `.health > 0` (or alternatively add an `alive method`). Anything you choose will be better than messing with Python's internals.